# user  login security - local cookie vs sessions

Tags: security, cookies, authentication

I've read a few answers here about this topic, and people say that using sessions is more secure that using only cookie, but I don't see how can that be true.

Let's say you're using sessions, and on the client's computer only the session ID is stored. If a hacker gains access to the client's computer and steals the session ID cookie, he practically gains access to the client's account on my site, right?

Now if you're using only local cookies, and store like a hashed portion of the the clients password + combined with a salt that only your server knows, a hacker can still gain access to his account by stealing his cookie from his PC.

So in the end there's no difference between the two methods, right? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: In case of session, you can put more layers. E.g. Ips.  Or locations these added layers prevents hijack even if someone steal the session. Its not unbreakable, but definitely harder to break.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, if a hacker gains full access to your computer, you're stuffed either way until the session is invalidated on the server-side.

If you only rely on cookies for sessions, it doesn't really matter if you use a session ID or a hash of the user's credentials plus a salt unique to that user. They are equivalent, so long as you can adjust the salt on the server to invalidate the cookie value. Often you would apply two salts: one defined per user and one that applies to all users. That way you can invalidate all the sessions for all users if you want, or just selected users.

There is a good reason to not use cookies for sessions, however: to protect against cross-site request forgery (XSRF). E.g. where you go to an attacker's website and it calls a page on your bank's website and transfers money out of your account. If your bank's website uses cookies for sessions, it will log you in successfully because the browser will automatically pass the session cookie to the site.

The way to avoid this is to pass the session ID in the payload of the request instead of as a cookie and, on the server-side, only look at the session token in the payload to determine the session, never the cookie.

Comment: Yes it is a good idea to have another session identifier in the request payload to guard against CSRF. I would also make sure this is send as a POST request instead of a GET request to guard against the value being stored in browser history, proxy history, server logs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the point that there must be a `team play` in cookie, database and session.

To get a fair amount of security, do these steps:

1. When the user successfully logs in with Remember Me checked, a login cookie is issued in addition to the standard session management cookie.
2. The login cookie contains the user's username and a random number (the "token" from here on) from a suitably large space. The username and token are stored as a pair in a database table.
3. When a non-logged-in user visits the site and presents a login cookie, the username and token are looked up in the database.

   - If the pair is present, the user is considered authenticated. The used token is removed from the database. A new token is generated, stored in database with the username, and issued to the user via a new login cookie.
   - If the pair is not present, the login cookie is ignored.
4. Users that are only authenticated via this mechanism are not permitted to access certain protected information or functions such as changing a password, viewing personally identifying information, or spending money. To perform those operations, the user must first successfully submit a normal username/password login form.
5. Since this approach allows the user to have multiple remembered logins from different browsers or computers, a mechanism is provided for the user to erase all remembered logins in a single operation.

This comes from Charles Miller's [article](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/), "Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice"

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your question and nothing more, sessions are more secure in the sense that the data stored in client (session ID) is usable by hackers only for a period of time before they are expired automatically. But if you keep any part of login information on client-side (as cookies) they will be valid as long as they are not changed by user. You can even regenerate session id by each request to reduce the lifespan of a session ID as short as possible.

[EDIT]

Let's call the information stored in client `The Key`. It can be a session ID or hashed login information. Using this key user can authenticate his request. Now if someone else steals `The Key`, he can do anything the user can do. The impostor doesn't need to decrypt `The Key` in order to use it, as long as he can copy it, it will do. The only way to stop the impostor is to invalidate `The Key`. So it doesn't matter what is your key, as long as it can be copied. The thing that matters is when and how you will invalidate it.

Comment: If you keep a hash with a salt only the server knows (as the OP suggests) you can invalidate the cookie, by changing the server salt, just as easily as invalidating a session ID.

Comment: And how would you know which salt to use for which request? Won't you need a session ID for that? Theoretically speaking, it's always safer to not expose vital information more than encrypting them.

Comment: If it's a secure hash (SHA-1 say) and you salt it, then you are not exposing anything. The salt can be stored with each user's account and the combination is effectively a session ID. They are equivalent, unless the same salt is applied to all users. Often you would apply two salts: one per user and one for all users. That way you can invalidate all the sessions for all users if you want, or just selected users.